# Configuring Office Web App Server for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, owa

We have a requirement to install and configure Office Web App Server for SharePoint 2013. Our Production environment is already has Office Web App Server 2013 integrated with Lync Server 2013 to use PowerPoint presentations in Lync Online Meetings. Now we had a requirement to add SharePoint Server 2013 to use browser based file viewing feature. My question how can i integrate SharePoint Server 2013 on the same OWA Server if its possible or do i need another OWA server for SharePoint 2013.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same WAC server/farm for your SharePoint farm that you currently use with Lync. Simply run `New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName wac.example.com` to hook up SharePoint to WAC.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, can i also use the same certificate which was used to configure Lync or a separate cert is required. Thanks again.

Comment: The certificate is on the WAC side.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, i see two certificates on the WAC server 1) WACServername 2) OfficeWebApp. Also the /hosting/discovery loads ok.  And when i run Get-OfficeWebAppFarm i get results with "InternalURL : https://WACServer.contoso.com" and "ExternalURL: https://WebApps.contoso.com" and i also see the CertificateName : WACServername. So is it ok to use New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName wac.example.com  and should not impact OWA for Lync and ignore the second certificate named OfficeWebApp?

Comment: `New-SPWOPIBinding` uses whatever certificate you've set that shows on the WAC configuration in `Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm`. The certificate assigned to the WAC farm configuration must be valid for your URLs configured for the WAC farm.